# Select first string using QRegularExpression

Tags: string, qt, qregexp

How do I get the first string (`"firstStr"` for the examples below) using QRegularExpression

```
QString readCmdOutput = "";
/* readCmdOutput = "firstStr\secondStr"; or 
readCmdOutput = "firstStr
secondStr
"
*/
readCmdOutput = QString::fromLocal8Bit(myProcess->readAllStandardOutput());  

QRegularExpression re("REGEXPRESSION");
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(readCmdOutput);
if (match.hasMatch()) { 
   QString matched2 = match2.captured(0);  // has to contain "firstStr"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct regular expression is:

```
QRegularExpression re("[^\\n\\\\]*");
```

This regular expression matches every sequence of characters not containing a line break (\n) or a backslash (\). Note that you have to escape all backslashes.
See [QRegularExpression](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpression.html) for more details.